# Are ἄρσην, ἄρσις and θήλυ, θέσις etymologically related?

Tags: etymology, word-comparison, ancient-greek, gender, music

In [Mt. 19:14](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Matthew%2019.4&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.01.0155), "[άρσεν](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%AC%CF%81%CF%83%CE%B5%CE%BD#lexicon) και [θήλυ](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?la=greek&l=%CE%B8%CE%AE%CE%BB%CF%85#lexicon)" means "male and female".

In music terminology [ἄρσις](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/11115) means a stressed/emphasized sound, and [θέσις](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/200655) the corresponding unstressed one.

Is ἄρσις etymologically related to άρσεν (male = active sex) and θέσις etymologically related to θήλυ (female = passive sex)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What a coincidence, but they're actually unrelated.

ἄρσην ("male") is the Greek form of an old Proto-Indo-European word **uers-n-*, with plenty of cognates in IE languages. It is actually related to the Latin *verres* 'ram' and other words in Sanskrit, Armenian, and Lithuanian referring to the male of an animal's species.

Meanwhile, ἄρσις comes from ἀείρω meaning "to raise up." An ἄρσις is thus a raising. The exact etymology of ἀείρω is uncertain, but Beekes reconstructs the PIE form as **h<sub>2</sub>uer-*, which as you can see is a very different looking form.

θήλυς and θέσις follow a similar trajectory. The former is derived from the PIE **d<sup>h</sup>eh-*, which means "to suckle." It is etymologically related to the Greek θηλή ('nipple') and the English *female* (from the Latin *femina*).

θέσις instead is derived from the verb τίθημι, and means "a placing" or a 'setting down.' It is actually where we get the English "thesis" from, as a 'topic set down [for discussion].' (Notice in fact the parallelism with the English *position*, from the Latin *positio*, meaning 'a setting down, a placing.')

So no, they're not directly related, but what might be interesting to explore is whether these were the words chosen because of their similarities to 'male' and 'female.' That I don't have an answer for, at least not without reading every place they're discussed, but I suppose it is possible.

Comment: I believe it's been proposed that the *dʰeh₁- of θήλυς and the *dʰeh₁- of τίθημι are actually the same PIE root (the semantics being "place (at the breast)" > "suckle"), so it's possible though unprovable that the latter pair are related.

Comment: @TKR Homophones in PIE always make me wonder if there's a connection. Do you know who published that? I didn't see it in Beekes.

Comment: I don't, and Chantraine doesn't mention it either. Maybe someone here will know.

Comment: @TKR Could be a good new question in itself.